# WPF data binding issues

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I am very new to WPF, and I am currently experimenting with data binding. I am getting the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Type' property not found on 'object'     ''Multimedia' (HashCode=15767257)'. BindingExpression:Path=Type; DataItem='Multimedia' (HashCode=15767257); target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')
```

The label I am trying to bind an attribute to looks like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Type}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="316,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I am setting a Multimedia object as my data context, which has the Type property. This is how I set the DataContext:

```
InitializeComponent();
selected = new Multimedia("title", "artist", "genre", Multimedia.MediaType.CD);
this.DataContext = selected;
mediaList.ItemsSource = list;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When does selected get set? also, where is medialist defined? need more XAML

Comment: in your context, what is the meaning of "this" it is important to find out what you are setting "selected" as the DataContext for.

Comment: medialist and selected are both defined and initialized in the xaml.cs file. For now, selected is just initialized with some dummy stuff, to see if I can get the values to appear on the GUI. "this" refers to the Main Window, which is currently the only one.

Comment: Also, does the class Multimedia have a property called "Type"?

Comment: can you provide the full code, because its kinda hard to fish for the problem? thank you

Comment: Yes it does, but it was set to private (Damn it..) After making it public, the binding is now possible. Thanks for the question, I wouldn't have noticed this "super-smart" mistake by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, even though the Multimedia object had the property, it was set to private. (D'oh!) After I made it public, it can now see it. Thanks a lot guys, the clarifying questions in the comments led me to the answer!